# Error: No Sequelize instance passed - Node.js, Sequelize v6, and TypeScript index.ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

Im trying to convert a server codebase in backend Node.js to TypeScript but I got a major setback in the models folder where all the sequelize models are instantiated.

In the models folder are all of the model files and an index.js file where I can import any model from this single file.

Here is the JS version:

```
const decamelize = require('decamelize');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);

let dbHost, dbName, dbPassword, dbUsername;
if (global.config) {
  dbName = global.config.dbName || "EXAMPLEDBNAME";
  dbUsername = global.config.dbUsername;
  dbPassword = global.config.dbPassword;
  dbHost = global.config.dbHost;
} else {
  // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
  const config = require('../config');
  dbName = config.get('dbName');
  dbUsername = config.get('dbUsername');
  dbPassword = config.get('dbPassword');
  dbHost = config.get('dbHost');
}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbName, dbUsername, dbPassword, {
  host: dbHost,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  logging: false,

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 10000,
    idle: 10000
  },

  define: {
    charset: 'utf8',
    collate: 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    paranoid: true, // defines a deleted at column instead of deleting items
    underscored: true,
  }
});

// Underscore attributes
sequelize.addHook('beforeDefine', (attributes, options) => {
  Object.keys(attributes).forEach((key) => {
      if (typeof attributes[key] !== "function" ) {
          attributes[key].field = decamelize(key);
      }
  });
});

const db = {};

// eslint-disable-next-line no-sync,arrow-body-style
fs.readdirSync(__dirname).filter(file => {
  return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
}).forEach(file => {
  const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize);
  db[model.name] = model;
});

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sql = sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

And here is what I have done in TypeScript:

```
import { ModelAttributeColumnOptions, Sequelize, Transaction } from "sequelize";
import decamelize from "decamelize";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import config from "../config";
import global from "../utils/config.default";
import Business from "./business";
import BusinessAuth from "./business-auth";
import SupportedDevice from "./supported-device";
import SupportedApp from "./supported-app";
import Reversal from "./reversal";
import Lane from "./lane";
import GibraltaConfig from "./gibralta-config";
import Configuration from "./configuration";
import CloudSaleLog from "./cloud-sale-log";
import DeviceError from "./device-error";
import DeviceChange from "./device-change";
import Device from "./device";
import CardReader from "./card-reader";

interface IExtendedAttributeColumnOptions extends ModelAttributeColumnOptions {
  field?: string;
}

interface IDb {
  sql: Sequelize;
  sequelize: Sequelize;
  Sequelize: Sequelize;
  BusinessAuth: BusinessAuth;
  Business: Business;
  CardReader: CardReader;
  Device: Device;
  DeviceChange: DeviceChange;
  DeviceError: DeviceError;
  CloudSaleLog: CloudSaleLog;
  Configuration: Configuration;
  GibraltaConfig: GibraltaConfig;
  Lane: Lane;
  Reversal: Reversal;
  SupportedApp: SupportedApp;
  SupportedDevice: SupportedDevice;
  Transaction: Transaction;

  // Add other models here
}

interface IModel {
  name: string;
  associate?: (models: IDb) => void;
  // Add other properties and methods here
}
const basename = path.basename(__filename);

let dbHost: string, dbName: string, dbPassword: string, dbUsername: string;

if (global.config) {
  dbName = global.config.dbName || "EXAMPLEDBNAME";
  dbUsername = (global as any).config.dbUsername;
  dbPassword = (global as any).config.dbPassword;
  dbHost = (global as any).config.dbHost;
} else {
  dbName = config.get("dbName");
  dbUsername = config.get("dbUsername");
  dbPassword = config.get("dbPassword");
  dbHost = config.get("dbHost");
}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbName, dbUsername, dbPassword, {
  host: dbHost,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  logging: false,

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 10000,
    idle: 10000
  },

  define: {
    charset: 'utf8',
    collate: 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true,
  }
});


// Underscore attributes
sequelize.addHook('beforeDefine', (attributes, options) => {
  Object.keys(attributes).forEach((key) => {
      if (typeof attributes[key] !== "function" ) {
          (attributes[key] as IExtendedAttributeColumnOptions).field = decamelize(key);
      }
  });
});

const tempDB: any = {};

fs.readdirSync(__dirname).filter(file => {
  return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
}).forEach(file => {
  const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize);
  tempDB[model.name] = model;
});

Object.keys(tempDB).forEach(modelName => {
  if (tempDB[modelName].associate) {
    tempDB[modelName].associate(tempDB);
  }
});

tempDB.sql = sequelize;
tempDB.sequelize = sequelize;
tempDB.Sequelize = Sequelize;

const db: IDb = tempDB as IDb;

export = db;
```

And this is one example of my model 'reversal':

```
import {
  Model,
  DataTypes,
  InferAttributes,
  InferCreationAttributes,
  Association,
  CreationOptional,
  ForeignKey,
  NonAttribute,
} from "sequelize";
import Lane from "./lane";
import Transaction from "./transaction";
import db from ".";
const sequelize = db.sequelize;

class Reversal extends Model<
  InferAttributes<Reversal>,
  InferCreationAttributes<Reversal>
> {
  declare id: CreationOptional<string>;
  declare attempts: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare nextAttempt: CreationOptional<Date>;
  declare activeAttempt: CreationOptional<Date>;
  declare deleteReversal: CreationOptional<boolean>;

  declare transactionId: ForeignKey<Transaction['id']>;
  declare laneId: ForeignKey<Lane['id']>;

  declare transaction: NonAttribute<Transaction>;
  declare lane: NonAttribute<Lane>;

  declare createdAt: CreationOptional<Date>;
  declare modifiedAt: CreationOptional<Date>;
  declare deletedAt?: CreationOptional<Date>;

  declare static associations: {
    Transaction: Association<Reversal, Transaction>;
    Lane: Association<Reversal, Lane>;
  };
}

Reversal.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4, // or v1?
    },
    attempts: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0,
    },
    nextAttempt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0,
    },
    activeAttempt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0,
    },
    deleteReversal: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    modifiedAt: DataTypes.DATE,
  },
  {
    tableName: "reversals",
    sequelize,
  }
);

Reversal.belongsTo(Transaction, {
  as: "transaction",
});
Reversal.belongsTo(Lane, {
  as: "lane",
});

export default Reversal;
```

Now when I run this I get this error:
`Error: No Sequelize instance passed at Function.init (/home/shifatqs/airpay-shield/node_modules/sequelize/src/model.js:960:13) at Object.<anonymous> (/home/shifatqs/airpay-shield/src/models/gibralta-config.ts:33:16) at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14) at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10) at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32) at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12) at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19) at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18) at Object.<anonymous> (/home/shifatqs/airpay-shield/src/models/configuration.ts:12:1) at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14) at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10) at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32) at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12) at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19) at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18) at Object.<anonymous> (/home/shifatqs/airpay-shield/src/models/business.ts:11:1) at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14) at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10) at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32) at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12) at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19) at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18) (node:29516) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'sequelize' of module exports inside circular dependency`

I have tried trying to find this circular dependency but with no luck and the code runs on the previous JS version including the database.

Note: the database itself is PostgreSQL

Comment: You have circular dependency